# Ordem de execução de expressão CASE pesquisada

Tags: sql, sql-server

O `CASE WHEN` possui duas formas de funcionamente, com expressões simples e pesquisada:

> A expressão **CASE simples** compara uma expressão com um conjunto de
>   expressões simples para determinar o resultado.
>
> A expressão **CASE pesquisada** avalia um conjunto de expressões boolianas
>   para determinar o resultado.

Na documentação é dito que o CASE WHEN para na primeira instrução satisfatória, mas em algumas situações a expressão é avalida primeiro:

> A instrução CASE avalia suas condições em sequência e para com a
>   primeira condição satisfatória. Em algumas situações, uma expressão é
>   avaliada antes de uma instrução CASE receber os resultados da
>   expressão como sua entrada. É possível que haja erros na avaliação
>   dessas expressões. As expressões agregadas que aparecem em argumentos
>   WHEN de uma instrução CASE são avaliadas primeiro e, em seguida, são
>   fornecidas para a instrução CASE.

[CASE - Transect SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)

Fiquei com dúvida em como o SQL executa as instruções na ordem em como ele le as expressões, mais específico no exemplo abaixo:

```
CASE
   WHEN validado = 0 THEN 
    1
   WHEN (SUBQUERY COM FUNÇÃO DE AGREGAÇÃO) > 0 THEN
    2
   WHEN MAX(valor) > 0 THEN 
    3
END
```

Se a primeira expressão for verdadeira o sql não executará a subquery?

Comment: não... é prq ele executaria ? .

Comment: Em algumas linguagens, se não me falha a memória, se não haver um break ou return todos os casos dentro de um switch são verificados. Mas se na documentação é informado que ele para na primeira ele não vai seguir. Se você precisa que os demais sejam validados, recomendaria a estrutura do IF mesmo.